# How to compress all tables in oracle database

Tags: oracle

I have tried many combinations, such as

```
alter ALL_TABLES MOVE COMPRESS
```

or

```
begin
for t in (SELECT table_name FROM user_tables where compression='DISABLED') loop
  execute immediate 'alter table ' || t.table_name || ' move compress';
end loop;
end;
```

None of them actually works.

Comment: The first statement has no sense, since ALL_TABLES is a native Oracle's view. As to the second one - how do you know "None of them actually works"? How do you check?

Comment: @PavelSmirnov For the second one, the query will not end no matter I type `;` or `end;`, it just kept listing numbers, waiting for the input, like `3 ;`, `4 end;`, 5...

Comment: That code works pretty fine. Are you sure you have posted exactly the same code you're running? If it's waiting for input, there are probably bind variables in the code.

Comment: @PavelSmirnov I run the code in `sqlplus`, the problem still exists.

Comment: Type in a slash `/` after the code *on a new line*. It will notify `sqlplus` that you've finished writing the code and it can be executed.